# PlayFramework passing execution context when using CompletableFutures and java

Tags: java, playframework, concurrency, completable-future

In [this section of the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools) they explain how to do this for `scala`

```
Future {
  // Some blocking or expensive code here
}(myExecutionContext)
```

What is the equivalent of this when you use `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
  // Some blocking or expensive code here
}, someCustomExecutor);
```

**How do we make sure context is available when using `java` and `CompletableFuture`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    // Some blocking or expensive code here
}, play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecution.defaultContext());
```

From [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/libs/concurrent/HttpExecution.html):

> ExecutionContexts that preserve the current thread's context ClassLoader and Http.Context.

See also the docs for [`play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/libs/concurrent/HttpExecutionContext.html).